# Scripts not rendering properly after bundling in asp.net

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, datatable

So I had some external scripts being called on one of my views. I searched the URL, copied and pasted each function into a new js script locally. Then I bundled my script files in bundle config. The functions were rendering find and displaying correctly.But now after bundling and then trying to use `@Script.Render`. The display is slightly messed up.

**Before**

[image]

**After**

[image]

I've checked spelling and the paths were correct, so why is `@Script.render` not working, when essentially the same scripts worked before. Does jQuery have a tendency to not work when bundled or something?

Let me know if you have additional questions or need to see code..

**Scripts:**

```
 <script src="~/Scripts/tools/jquerydatatables.js"> </script>
 <script src="~/Scripts/tools/responsivebootstrap.js"></script>


 <script src="~/Scripts/tools/bootstrapdatatable.js"></script>

  <script src="~/Scripts/tools/responsivedatatable.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/tools/cloudpopper.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/tools/twitter.js"></script>
```

Bundle:

```
 bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/scripts/desktop")
            .Include(

            "~/Scripts/tools/bootstrapdatatable.js",
            "~/Scripts/tools/cloudpopper.js",
            "~/Scripts/tools/jquerydatatables.js",
            "~/Scripts/tools/responsivebootstrap.js",
            "~/Scripts/tools/responsivedatatable.js",
            "~/Scripts/tools/twitter.js"


            ));
```

css sheet is linked with:`<link href="//cdn.datatables.net/1.10.18/css/dataTables.bootstrap4.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />`

but my css sheet is not bundled with the java script, but that shouldn't be a problem right?

This is the code that messes up the display when I use it:`@section Scripts{
        @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/scripts/desktop")`

Comment: Please show us your code. Also it looks more like a CSS issue than a JS issue.

Comment: We would like to see more of your code and when did it stop working?

Comment: code is updated

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can see you have a css issue:
If you want to bundle css you need to use `Styles.Render("~/css/myVirtualPath")`.
In bundle config class then you put something like this:

```
 bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("~/css/myVirtualPath").Include("~/Styles/myStyle.css"))
```

Comment: my css is linked with href, but it is not bundled with the scripts..that shouldn't matter though right? I updated the question with code snippets.

Comment: Can u please share all css links because i dont see bootstrap in there

Comment: <link href="//cdn.datatables.net/1.10.18/css/dataTables.bootstrap4.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />  is the only one for that page

Comment: Then u need to include more styles. The only one obviously missing is bootstrap 4. Please check datatables for bootstrap 4 docs and see what links are necessary to be included in the page

Comment: https://datatables.net/examples/styling/bootstrap4 u have an example here